# Can I inherit test suite variables and libraries?

Tags: robotframework

I have a robot test suite that contains child test suites, and those have their own child test suites.
All tests use a certain set of variables and libraries.

As far as I can tell, I have to define the variables and import the libraries in every single test suite.  I hope I'm just missing a trick -- is there a better way to make these things available to all tests at all levels of the hierarchy?

Bonus points if I can do it in a way that supports keyword completion in RIDE.  I'm using RIDE 1.2.3 and robot 2.8.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one main resource where you import everything and then import only that main resource in every test suite.

Comment: begining of the answer is correct bu the "or create __init__.txt in the folder where your tests are"  does not work because "Variables and keywords created or imported in initialization files are not available in the lower level test suites" (from http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#initialization-files)

Comment: And further, you can effectively "inherit" resource files by importing "parent" resource files into "child" files.  Then when your test or suite imports the child resource file, it inherits all the resources imported by it (any depth).

Comment: This way , if I am using the same library in 100 suites I will have to repeat the import (library or resource file) 100 times. Is there really no easier way to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can wire a resource file and polulate it with Keywords that can be imported into your test suites and test cases.
Read the [detailed explaination](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/source/browse/doc/userguide/src/CreatingTestData/ResourceAndVariableFiles.txt?r=6b2daa1085ea6b8c3a51b1792355756011c7511d).